Google slides problem with selecting part of the slide
When doing a google slides it is not possible to download just a part of the slide as a picture. So for example, I need to select part of the slide and turn it into a picture. Like a screenshot would be using cmd+shift+4 on mac but screenshots loose quality and I need it not to loose quality
tried to do download as a png and cut but looses a lot of quality
